# Puppeteer for scraping a page (with authentication)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, screen-scraping

I am using puppeteer for scraping a page (load test application) and I cannot add username and password into this page. Does anyone of you know puppeteer and may help me? This is the code:

````
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(“https://d22syekf1i694k.cloudfront.net/”, {waitUntil: ‘networkidle2’});
    await page.waitForSelector(‘input[name=username]’);
    await page.type(‘input[name=username]’, ‘Adenosine’);
    await page.$eval(‘input[name=username]’, el => el.value = ‘Adenosine’);
    await browser.close();
})(); ```
````

Comment: like if you try to do that with gmail it will just prevent you from doing it since it recognizes puppeteer.. maybe whatever site you're trying to bot has similar software

Comment: This a load tester site running in my environment... I don't see any blockers for scraping in the site... It's a public website (open to web) and everyone can try it

Comment: gmail is also public to everyone